# I would like to find out how to get the remaining points a user needs to level up

Tags: javascript, node.js, math, discord.js, calculation

Sorry, I'm really bad at math and I also don't know the English terms so I really don't know how to ask this question properly.

I'm using this to calculate a users level

`const curLevel = Math.floor(0.2 * Math.sqrt(score.points));`

I would like to find out how to get the remaining points a user needs to level up. I didn't really try anything yet because I have **no idea** where to begin, might even be something super simple...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the number of points needed to reach the next integer level by solving for points in the equation `curLevel + 1 = 0.2 * Math.sqrt(nextLevelPoint)`.
You get that you can calculate the total points needed for the next level with:

```
let nextLevelPoint = Math.pow(5*curLevel + 5, 2)
```

Subtract `score.point` from this `nextLevelPoint` and you get the remaining points a user needs to level up.